# Java enum that registers as listener on creation

Tags: java, enums, singleton, listener

There are two good (as considered by most) java practices that i try to combine and fail.

1. Never leak *this* in a constructor.
2. Use *enum* instead of singleton pattern.

So, I want a singleton that as soon as created, listens for some event. Here's an example. First, the event listener interface:

```
public interface EventListener {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Then, the event producer:

```
public class EventProducer implements Runnable{

    private EventListener listener;

    public EventProducer(EventListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Listener should not be null.");
        }
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listener.doSomething(); //This may run before the listener is initialized.
        do {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long currentTime;
            do {
                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } while ((currentTime - startTime) < 1000);
            listener.doSomething();
        } while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        listener = null; //Release the reference so the listener may be GCed
    }
}
```

Then, the enum (as the 2nd listed java practice suggests):

```
public enum ListenerEnum implements EventListener{

    INSTANCE;

    private int counter;
    private final ExecutorService exec;

    private ListenerEnum() {
        EventProducer ep = new EventProducer(this); //Automatically unregisters when the producer is done.
        counter = 0;
        exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        exec.submit(ep);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Did something.");
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 5) {
            exec.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, something to get things started:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListenerEnum.INSTANCE.doSomething();
    }

}
```

The problem lies in the first line of the *ListenerEnum* constructor, as we are leaking *this*, thus not conforming to the 1st listed java practice. This is why our event producer can call a listener's method before the listener is constructed.

How do I deal with this? Normally I would use a Builder pattern, but how is that possible with an enum?

**EDIT:**
For those that it matters, the event producer in my program actually extends a BroadcastReceiver, so my enum cannot be the event producer, they have to be separate. The producer is created in the constructor of the enum (as the example) and is registered programmatically later on. So I don't actually have a problem leaking *this*. Nevertheless, I'd like to know if I could avoid it.

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, since there are suggestions to solve my problem, i'd like to clarify some things. First of all, most suggestions are workarounds. They suggest doing the same thing in a completely different way. I appreciate the suggestions, and probably will accept one as answer and implement it. But the real question should be "How do i implement a Builder pattern with an enum?" The answer i already know and people suggest is "You don't, do it some other way.". Is there anyone who can post something like "You do! You do it this way."?

I was asked to give code close to my actual use case. Modify the following:

```
public enum ListenerEnum implements EventListener{

    INSTANCE;

    private EventProducer ep;
    private int counter;
    private ExecutorService exec;

    private ListenerEnum() {
        ep = new EventProducer(this); //Automatically unregisters when the producer is done.
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void startGettingEvents() {
        exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        exec.submit(ep);
    }

    public void stopGettingEvents() {
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Did something.");
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 5) {
            stopGettingEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

As well as this:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListenerEnum.INSTANCE.startGettingEvents();
    }

}
```

Now all i have to do to solve my problem is move the EventsProducer creation to the *startGettingEvents()* method. That's it. But that is also a workaround. What i'd like to know is: In general, how do you avoid leaking *this* in the constructor of a listener enum since you can't use the Builder pattern? Or can you actually someway use the Builder pattern with an enum? Is it done only by workarounds in a case by case basis? Or is there a general way to deal with this that i don't know of?

Comment: Your enum pattern *is* a singleton. Also, why would the producer be part of the listener? (I.e., why do you create the producer in the constructor of the listener? Wouldn't it make more sense to just let the singleton produce the events by itself?)

Comment: Well, the way the example goes, you are right. But lets imagine for a moment that the producer is already created and the enum just registers as a listener in that line. Could change the code if that helps.

Comment: Interesting question. Why does this listener need to be a singleton?

Comment: Why does it have to register itself as soon as it is constructed? If you say that the producer is actually an independent object, and the singleton only registers to it, why not have a `register()` method?

Comment: @Duncan I'd like to have a singleton to handle internet connectivity issues. Any other class could then submit a Runnable to this enum to be run as soon as there is a connection (or immediately if there is already a connection). I think it is cleaner to have a singleton for that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic So when should i call _register(this)_? A few points come into my mind, for example as an extra line in _main()_ to create the producer and one more to register the enum as listener. That could be a fix. Maybe you should post the comment as answer. EDIT: In this case however, i'd miss any events happening after the producer is created, and before the enum registers.

Comment: Frankly, though I'd like to earn the reputation, I'm not sure I understand your problem well enough to create a proper answer from my suggestion, especially now that you have edited and mentioned that you already register at a different place and that leaking `this` was not an issue, which confused me. It would be more helpful if you presented an example that was a little more similar to your real usage case.

Comment: @cdriver Please note that people can review your question's history if they want to. So your edits would be best if they leave your question concise and up-to-date, rather than laden with "Edit X: ....", "Edit Y: ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a static initialization block:

```
public enum ListenerEnum implements EventListener{

    INSTANCE;

    private int counter;
    private static final ExecutorService exec; //this looks strange. I'd move this service out of enum.
    private static final EventProducer ep;

    static{
            exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            ep = new EventProducer(INSTANCE); //Automatically unregisters when the producer is done.
            exec.submit(ep); 
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Did something.");
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 5) {
            exec.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

As long as enum values are final and static they [are initialized before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.1) the static initialization block. If you decompile the enum you'll see a single initialization block:

```
        static{
                INSTANCE = new ListenerEnum();
                exec.submit(INSTANCE.ep); 
        }
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Please edit it so i can accept it. 1. exec has to be static. 2. The static constructor goes after the exec declaration. 3. The exec creations also goes in the static constructor. Then it works, and does exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: `enum` values are *always* implicitly `static final` and guaranteed to be initialized before any other `static` block. That’s why you can’t place `static` initializer blocks before than, so it’s all consistent. But decompiling is not a proper way to prove whether a particular behavior is *guaranteed*. You have to refer to the specification.

Comment: And by the way, to completely avoid leaking `this`, you also have to make `ep` static, move the `ep = new EventProducer()` line in the static initialization block, and change `exec.submit(INSTANCE.ep)` to `exec.submit(ep)`. Should i make the changes?

Comment: If you are going to have only one instance it does not make sense. ep should be final, but not static. This is actually up to you. personally I'd move exec out of enum. The rest of architecture heavily depends on environment of this class.

Comment: Your modified code still allows `this` to leak from the enum constructor.

Comment: @Mikhail There's going to be only one instance (signleton), and if ep is static, there's only going to be one instance of it too. So, what doesn't make sence? As for the exec, in the actual case it doesn't exist. The producer is a BroacastReceiver in android, i don't need an executor, it's not a runnable.

Comment: @Duncan The static initialization block would be like this (compiled as Mikhail says) `static { INSTANCE = new ListenerEnum(); ep = new EventProducer(INSTANCE); exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); exec.submit(ep); }`. The INSTANCE is fully initialized when used, but the ListenerEnum class is not, since the static initialization block is still running. So is that a leak or not?

Comment: @cdriver Yes, I think there's still a leak. Since `this` escapes during `new ListenerEnum()`, the problems described in my answer can still occur.

Comment: I suppose the problem is in `new EventProducer(this)`. if this class starts thread or publishes reference further, that could be a concurrency issue.

Comment: @Duncan `private ListenerEnum() { counter = 0; }` does not leak `this`. However, i'm thinking about the case that the EventProducer is calling a method of INSTANCE before the static initialization block has finished executing. What happens then? Mind boggling.

Comment: @Duncan Could you please modify the code to have a working thing talking about? Do you want me to do it?

Comment: @cdriver I'm confused - I've not seen a code sample on this page where the only thing the constructor does is `counter = 0`.

Comment: @Mikhail Sorry, I've editing your answer, please comment on this.

Comment: @cdriver This is not my answer, it's Mikhail's.

Comment: Yeah, edited the comment, this code is working know. But is there a leak? To repeat the question: I'm thinking about the case that the EventProducer is calling a method of INSTANCE before the static initialization block has finished executing. What happens then?

Comment: @cdriver It looks good to me, quite a nice way of solving the problem (ignoring all our chat about singletons). There is no leak (of `this`), since the object is already constructed.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider *why* `this` shouldn’t escape:

1. You loose the `final` field safe publication guaranty in case of an improper publication of the instance
2. Even with a safe publication there are inconsistencies regarding all action not performed within the constructor at the time of the leakage
3. You will let escape an incomplete instance in case of subclasses as the subclass’ constructor hasn’t been called so far

That doesn’t apply to you in this narrow case. Submitting to an `Executor` is not an improper publication and `enum`’s can’t escape in any other way besides the one you have implemented yourself in the constructor. And its the last thing in the constructor whereas `enum`s can’t have subclasses.

---

Now that you have edited your question, it makes much lesser sense. The constructor

```
private ListenerEnum() {
    ep = new EventProducer(this);
    counter = 0;
}
```

is not a “leaking `this`” as long as `ep` is not a `static` variable and the constructor of `EventProducer` does not let leak its `this` as well. This is important as programmers must be able to create circular object graphs without fearing sudden inconsistencies.

But it is still nothing you should take too easy. As said, it relies on the behavior of the `EventProducer` regarding leakage and regarding that `EventProducer` must not call back into `ListenerEnum` which could break things without being a “leaking `this`”, technically. After all, you can create code that breaks without breaking thread safety.

So it’s code for which you can’t see the correctness when looking at it as you need knowledge about another class.

There are use cases where passing `this` to another object is considered safe because of well-known behavior, e.g. `weakThis=new WeakReference(this);` is a real-life example. However, passing `this` to something called `EventProducer` is likely to let alarm bells ringing for every reader which you should avoid even if you know for sure that it’s false-alarm.

---

However, the big design smell lies in the use of the Singleton pattern in itself. After all, every instance you create is unique in the first place. What is special about the Singleton pattern is that it provides global `public` access to that instance. Is that really what you want? Did you consider that by using the Singleton pattern, everyone inside the entire application could register that listener again?

Comment: I agree that leaking _this_ is not a problem in my case. I disagree that the singleton pattern is to be avoided. But that's another talk, repeated many times.

Comment: @cdriver I believe leaking `this` is a problem in your case, see my updated answer. Because of this, I'm down-voting this answer as I believe it's incorrect. Comments welcome of course.

Comment: @Duncan: submitting to an `Executor` creates a happens-before relationship that guarantees that all action made prior to submitting are visible to the executing thread. So since it is the last step in the constructor, it *is* constructed. However, I didn’t recommend this design though.

Comment: @Holger The current code does not submit to the executor within the constructor. Therefore I believe it remains an unsafe publication. Could you comment on my example in my answer? (Either here or under my answer).

Comment: @Duncan: I wrote my answer before that edit. And I was referring to the `submit` as the construction of another object (here `EventProducer`) isn’t a publication per se.

Comment: What is your definition of a "leaking `this`"? Everything I've read suggests this does technically count as one. But you seem adamant it doesn't - what are you basing this on? My understanding of the definition is very simple - if you pass `this` to another class during construction, it is a leak.

Comment: @Duncan: “leaking `this`” is a term that normally refers to the possibility that a different thread can see it. So it includes all stores in `static` variables or in instance fields of objects that are themselves already visible (or may become visible before end of construction) or passing it to any piece of code which may perform one of these stores, directly or indirectly. So of course, passing it to code about which you don’t know, should be considered a potential leak as well. So this might be the reason for propagating the simplified rule “never pass `this` to any other class”.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your class is a singleton (whether enum-based or otherwise) is unrelated to your problem. Your problem is simply how to register a listener within the constructor of an object. And the answer is: it's not possible, safely.

I would recommend you do two things:

- Ensure your listener doesn't miss out on events by having a *queue* that it polls for work. This way, if it temporarily isn't listening, the work just queues up. In fact, this means it doesn't really need to be a listener in the traditional sense. It just needs to poll on a queue.
- Register the class as a listener using a separate method, as discussed in the comments.

I would give some thought to avoiding a singleton. It doesn't offer many advantages (asides from the minor benefit of being able to call `SomeClass.INSTANCE` from anywhere). The downsides are most strongly felt during testing, where you find it much harder to mock the class when you wish to test without actually sending things over the network.

---

Here's a concrete example of why leaking `this` is dangerous in your case. Your constructor passes `this` before setting counter to zero:

```
private ListenerEnum() {
    ep = new EventProducer(this);
    counter = 0;
}
```

Now, as soon as `this` escapes, your event producer might invoke `doSomething()` 5 times before the constructor completes:

```
@Override
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Did something.");
    counter++;
    if (counter >= 5) {
        exec.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

The sixth call to this method ought to fail right? Except that your constructor now finishes and sets `counter = 0;`. Thus allowing the producer to call `doSomething()` 5 more times.

Note: it doesn't matter if you reorder those lines as the constructor may not be executed in the order it appears in your code.

Comment: Nice suggestions, but i really like my singletons for what i use them, and i make sure i can test them. That's because the program gets closer to my way of thinking, so it makes it easier to handle it. Big talk. Anyway, if there wasn't a better answer, i'd pick yours as correct.

Comment: This is a special case here as the `EventProducer` is created within the constructor of `ListenerEnum` and remains local, therefore it isn’t a publication regarding thread-safety. It would be a problem if the `EventProducer` produces events inside its constructor but then it would be a bug within `EventProducer` as it either produces events out of nothing or has published itself to something capable of producing events.

Comment: @Holger From the perspective of this class, it's impossible to say what `EventProducer` will do when it receives a reference to `ListenerEnum` in its constructor. Thus one should defensively program as though it might do anything. The consequence of this is that we should choose a different design that doesn't leak `this`.

Comment: @Duncan: I agree that this is not recommended behavior but I still think that a question shouldn’t be answered technically incorrect. So it isn’t a leakage (per se) but still not recommended technique. I have edited my answer to make that clear, hopefully good enough for you to consider retracting the downvote.

Comment: @Holger I retracted my down-vote some time ago, someone else is to blame I'm afraid. I don't understand why you consider this not to be a leak. It is - any time `this` escapes a constructor, even in a single-threaded app, it is a leak. You are then reliant on other classes behaving reasonably to avoid unexpected behaviour.